# Installed 12.04 from Live CD, after login/password and updates completed, then all I get is a black screen and

Tags: 12.04

a arrow cursor.  I am very newbie, so need help in complete instructions, I am using 9.04 to ask here, it is the only way I knew to get online. Thanks Dolores

Answer (score -1):

i think you are getting the command line interface and not the graphical interface.

Try the `startx` command when the cursor shows up

Comment: The OP is getting an arrow cursor, not a command-line interface.